# Type Asserting Returned Data From Angular Http Client

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to wrap the data from an HttpClient call into a TypeScript class. The added benefit I'm looking for is to be able to define computed properties on that class from the data that will be returned by the service wrapping it. Is there a special way to assert the returned data is that type so that TypeScript treats it correctly and provides the computed properties?

I have tried simply using the `as` keyword, as well as defining the callback to `subscribe` with the correct type.

SomeType.ts

```js
export class SomeType {
    a: number;
    b: number;

    get sum(): number {
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
```

Service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SomeType } from 'some-type';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getData(): Observable<SomeType> {
        return this.http.get<SomeType>("/endpoint");
    }
}
```

Component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data: SomeType) => {
        console.log(typeof(this.service)); // Service

        console.log(data instanceof SomeType); // false
        console.log(typeof(data)); // Object
        console.log(data.a); // 1
        console.log(data.b); // 1
        console.log(data.sum); // undefined

        data = data as SomeType;
        console.log(data instanceof SomeType); // false
        console.log(typeof(data)); // Object
        console.log(data.a); // 1
        console.log(data.b); // 1
        console.log(data.sum); // undefined

        data = <SomeType>data;
        console.log(data instanceof SomeType); // false
        console.log(typeof(data)); // Object
        console.log(data.a); // 1
        console.log(data.b); // 1
        console.log(data.sum); // undefined
    });
}
```

Comment: By adding `<SomeType>` to the `get` call, you just tell the compiler, that the `get`method should return `SomeType`. It is only about type checking. The get method won't instantiate the `SomeType` for you. You should parse the response yourself to convert it to the `SomeType`, or use some parsing library.